# Adding multiple class using ng-class

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

> ALERT: This thread is for the old AngularJS!

Can we have multiple expression to add multiple ng-class ?

for eg.

```
<div ng-class="{class1: expressionData1, class2: expressionData2}"></div>
```

If yes can anyone put up the example to do so.

.

Comment: Your example works as-is.

Comment: Yes it does, I just had to use !important in css to make it visible. I found it by myself :)

Comment: What @stevuu said .. is ri8... ur question is answer

Comment: Does the value expressionData1 usually take on true/false, or some actually string value?

Answer (score 1111, accepted):

To apply different classes when different expressions evaluate to `true`:

```
<div ng-class="{class1 : expression1, class2 : expression2}">
    Hello World!
</div>
```

To apply multiple classes when an expression holds true:

```
<!-- notice expression1 used twice -->
<div ng-class="{class1 : expression1, class2 : expression1}">
    Hello World!
</div>
```

or quite simply:

```
<div ng-class="{'class1 class2' : expression1}">
    Hello World!
</div>
```

Notice the single quotes surrounding css classes.

Comment: you can not pass multiple class like ng-class="{'class1 class2' : expression1}" just test that and did not worked at all, solution as @CodeHater said "To apply multiple classes when an expression holds true:" that made the trick

Comment: In 1.2.16 the multi-class option (`'class1 class2': expression`) seems to work fine, except that if you reuse a class it is dropped when the expression toggles between the options. E.g. with `'commonClass class1': expression == true, 'commonClass class2': expression == false` commonClass is lost as the expression toggles between true and false.

Comment: @BrianS I would do something like this: `class="commonClass" ng-class={'class1' : expression, 'class2' : !expression}`

Comment: @CodeHater thanks. That's pretty much what I'm planning now, just need to take a moment to fix up the CSS.

Comment: Is `ng-class="{'class1' : expression1, 'class2':expression1 }"` possible?  Would you mind looking at my Question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25391692/adding-multiple-expressions-using-ng-class-in-angularjs

Comment: ng-class="{class1 : expression1, class2 : expression2}" condition is not working in safari.

Comment: What version of angular is this for?  It is not working for me.

Comment: if you have a class name with hyphen in it, you have to use apostrophes around it, otherwise it's not going to work.

Comment: Use ternary operator if you want to apply multiple class for the same condition for eg.
      [ngClass]="expression1 ? 'class1' : 'class2' "

Comment: The space on the last example is what I was looking for. I thought it needed a comma.

Answer (score 61):

For the ternary operator notation:

```html
<div ng-class="expression1? 'class1 class2' : 'class3 class4'">
```

Comment: This one doesn't work for me. <span ng-class="params.isAdmin?'fa fa-lock fa-2x':'fa fa-unlock fa-2x'"></span>. Console will throw error.

Comment: using this method, can I add another expression?

Comment: @HikeNalbandyan yes you can add another expression too: `ng-class="[expression1? 'class1 class2' : 'class3 class4', expression2 ? 'class5' : 'class6']"`

Comment: If I have a fixed style "timeString" and an optional one to add, depending on a condition "disabledText" how do I write that ?

Answer (score 58):

**An incredibly powerful alternative to other answers here:**

```
ng-class="[  { key: resulting-class-expression }[ key-matching-expression ], ..  ]"
```

**Some examples:**

1. Simply adds 'class1 class2 class3' to the div:

```
<div ng-class="[{true: 'class1'}[true], {true: 'class2 class3'}[true]]"></div>
```

2. Adds 'odd' or 'even' classes to div, depending on the $index:

```
<div ng-class="[{0:'even', 1:'odd'}[ $index % 2]]"></div>
```

3. Dynamically creates a class for each div based on $index

```
<div ng-class="[{true:'index'+$index}[true]]"></div>
```

If `$index=5` this will result in:

```
<div class="index5"></div>
```

**Here's a code sample you can run:**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []); 
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.items = 'abcdefg'.split('');
});
```

```css
.odd  { background-color: #eee; }
.even { background-color: #fff; }
.index5 {background-color: #0095ff; color: white; font-weight: bold; }
* { font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items"
    ng-class="[{true:'index'+$index}[true], {0:'even', 1:'odd'}[ $index % 2 ]]">
    index {{$index}} = "{{item}}" ng-class="{{[{true:'index'+$index}[true], {0:'even', 1:'odd'}[ $index % 2 ]].join(' ')}}"
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant answer! I've always used functions for more complex `ng-class` directives, such as when I needed to apply a ternary and a standard expression on the same element. I've submitted an edit to the accepted answer to include the use of arrays of expressions.

Comment: I'm not an Angular expert, but in seems that this construct: `[{true:'index'+$index}[true], {0:'even', 1:'odd'}[ $index % 2 ]]` can simplified like this `['index'+$index, {0:'even', 1:'odd'}[ $index % 2 ]]`. I've just tried it in Angular 1.5.9 and it works :) Thanks for a great answer!

Comment: @kit can you pls help me here [Similar SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65253111/fa-fa-icons-in-ng-class-with-ternary-operator-angular-js-1-x/65253772#65253772)

Answer (score 48):

Yes you can have multiple expression to add multiple class in ng-class.

For example:

```
<div ng-class="{class1:Result.length==2,class2:Result.length==3}"> Dummy Data </div>
```

Answer (score 30):

Using a `$scope` method on the controller, you can calculate what classes to output in the view. This is especially handy if you have a complex logic for calculating class names and it will reduce the amount of logic in your view by moving it to the controller:

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope) {

    $scope.className = function() {

        var className = 'initClass';

        if (condition1())
            className += ' class1';

        if (condition2())
            className += ' class2';

        return className;
    };
});
```

and in the view, simply:

```
<div ng-class="className()"></div>
```

Comment: If the class changes after render, is ng-class still listening for changes in `className`?

Comment: IMHO, the scope should only expose the _condition_.  It should be up to the HTML `ng-` bindings to determine what _class_ to use when that condition is met.

Comment: This overwrites the class attribute in dom elements. If one uses this, they have to include the classes that don't need conditions in the returned `className`.

Answer (score 23):

Your example works for conditioned classes (the class name will show if the `expressionDataX` is true):

`<div ng-class="{class1: expressionData1, class2: expressionData2}"></div>`

You can also add multiple classes, supplied by the user of the element:

`<div ng-class="[class1, class2]"></div>`

Usage:

`<div class="foo bar" class1="foo" class2="bar"></div>`

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to combine the two types of template, ie have a conditional class using `{}` and a data-bound class using `[]`?

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible. Also, it is not possible to put two `ngClass` directives on an element.

Comment: you'll be surprised: `<a href="#/u/[[msg.from]]" ng-bind="msg.from" class="name, ng-class:[users[msg.from].nice, users[msg.from].star];" ng-class="{premium: users[msg.from].premium}"></a>` and more: http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass

Comment: @jwg : you can combine two types of templates
ans is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29230732/how-to-combine-conditional-class-and-data-bound-class-in-angularjs/29231252#29231252

Answer (score 12):

Here is an example comparing multiple angular-ui-router states using the OR || operator:

```
<li ng-class="
    {
        warning:
            $state.includes('out.pay.code.wrong')
            || $state.includes('out.pay.failed')
        ,
        active:
            $state.includes('out.pay')
    }
">
```

It will give the li the classes warning and/or active, depening on whether the conditions are met.

Comment: I can't really remember. Isn't it logical though?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that multiple classes can be applied from the same ng-class block, as long as each of their conditions are satisfied.

Answer (score 6):

Below active and activemenu are classes and itemCount and ShowCart is expression/boolean values.

```
ng-class="{'active' : itemCount, 'activemenu' : showCart}"
```

Answer (score 6):

With multiple conditions

```
<div ng-class="{'class1' : con1 || can2, 'class2' : con3 && con4}">
Hello World!
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Found another way thanks to Scotch.io

```
<div ng-repeat="step in steps" class="step-container step" ng-class="[step.status, step.type]" ng-click="onClick(step.type)">
```

This was my reference.[PATH](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass)

Answer (score 3):

Other way we can create a function to control "using multiple class"

CSS

```
 <style>
    .Red {
        color: Red;
    }
    .Yellow {
        color: Yellow;
    }
      .Blue {
        color: Blue;
    }
      .Green {
        color: Green;
    }
    .Gray {
        color: Gray;
    }
    .b {
         font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
```

Script

```
<script>
    angular.module('myapp', [])
            .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                $scope.MyColors = ['It is Red', 'It is Yellow', 'It is Blue', 'It is Green', 'It is Gray'];
                $scope.getClass = function (strValue) {
                    if (strValue == ("It is Red"))
                        return "Red";
                    else if (strValue == ("It is Yellow"))
                        return "Yellow";
                    else if (strValue == ("It is Blue"))
                        return "Blue";
                    else if (strValue == ("It is Green"))
                        return "Green";
                    else if (strValue == ("It is Gray"))
                        return "Gray";
                }
        }]);
</script>
```

Using it

```
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="ExampleController">

<h2>AngularJS ng-class if example</h2>
<ul >
    <li ng-repeat="icolor in MyColors" >
        <p ng-class="[getClass(icolor), 'b']">{{icolor}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can refer to full code page at [ng-class if example](http://angularjsaz.blogspot.com/2015/09/ng-class-if-example.html)

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
[ngClass]="[{
    'basic':'mat-basic-button', 
    'raised':'mat-raised-button', 
    'stroked':'mat-stroked-button'
}[ 
    button.style ?? 'raised'
]]"
```