# AngularJS - How to add multiple ng-class directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

Here are 2 different ways to use the `ng-class` directive.  I need them both, on the same element, but that doesn't work.

## Using an object in ng-class

http://plnkr.co/edit/uZNK7I?p=preview

```
<div ng-repeat="item in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]" 
     ng-class="{ first: $first, last: $last }">{{item}}</div>
```

correctly results in

```
<div class="first">1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div class="last">5</div>
```

---

## Using an expression in ng-class

http://plnkr.co/edit/tp6lgR?p=preview

```
<div ng-repeat="item in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]" 
     ng-class=" 'count-' + ($index + 1) ">{{item}}</div>
```

correctly results in

```
<div class="count-1">1</div>
<div class="count-2">2</div>
<div class="count-3">3</div>
<div class="count-4">4</div>
<div class="count-5">5</div>
```

---

## Now, how about use them together?

I need dynamic class names (like `'count-' + n`), but also need the object syntax for multiple classes.

I can't just use 2 `ng-class` attributes (http://plnkr.co/edit/OLaYke?p=preview), only the first one works.

**Any suggestions?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `ng-class` for the second one, use

```
<div class="count-{{$index + 1}}" ng-class="{ first: $first, last: $last }">
```

Comment: This seems to work (http://plnkr.co/edit/OLaYke?p=preview), although I'm not sure about ie8 (and unfortunately plnkr doesn't work in ie8, and I don't have time to set this up and test it)

Comment: According to angular docs suggested solution is a bad practice: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass#known-issues 
See my answer below for recommended way to do it

Comment: @MaximKulikov - It doesn't say that anywhere, it says not to use interpolation. `{{}}` is different than the syntax displayed above.

Comment: @tymeJV `{{$index + 1}}` is an interpolation, and you suggest to use it in `class` attribute simultaneously with usage of `ngClass` directive

Comment: @tymeJV quote from documentation:
> You should not use interpolation in the value of the class attribute, when using the ngClass directive on the same element.

Comment: @MaximKulikov -- Hah - my fault, you're right - I definitely didn't see where I was using interp above (just focused on my ngClass) - good catch!

Answer (score 8):

You should provide `ngClass` with an array that contains both expression and object:

```
<div ng-class="['count-' + ($index + 1), { first: $first, last: $last }]">
```

***Note:***
The solution suggested in accepted answer (simultaneous usage of `ngClass` directive and interpolation in `class` attribute) is a bad practice. See more details [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass#known-issues) and [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#known-issues).

Answer (score 2):

If you need to mix them together, just go for strings concat:

```
ng-class="'count-' + ($index+1) + ($first?' first':($last?' last':''))"
```

Or for a clearer view:

```
ng-class="'count-' + ($index+1) + ($first?' first':'') + ($last?' last':'')"
```

There aren't known pros for using `class="{{exp}}"` instead of `ng-class="exp"`, since both get updated when the value of `exp` changes. On the contrary, going with the first one might cause page froze in some cases.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know we could use ternaries in the ng-class expression.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you can separate atributes `ng-class` with `;`

try:

```
ng-class=" 'count-' + ($index + 1) ; { first: $first, last: $last }"
```

Comment: This seems to work (http://plnkr.co/edit/OLaYke?p=preview), and this might be a better approach for ie8

Comment: This did not work for me, but this answer did the trick http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871277/adding-multiple-class-using-ng-class