# Dynamic ng-class value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a directive with this markup:

```
<button type="button" ng-class="{ 'btn-disabled': button.isDisabled }">
```

As you can see, `btn-disabled` is added as a CSS class if the scope's `button.isDisabled` is truthy.

Also on the scope is a property `button.glyphicon`. If `glyphicon` is truthy, I'd like to add the value of it to the `<button>`'s class as well.

How can I do this?

Comment: Hem… `{ 'btn-disabled': button.isDisabled, glyphicon: button.glyphicon }`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding multiple class using ng-class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871277/adding-multiple-class-using-ng-class)

Comment: Blackhole: no, the class "glyphicon" will be added, not the value of "glyphicon".

Comment: Then, use `ng-class="(button.isDisabled ? 'btn-disabled ' : ' ') + (button.glyphicon || '')"`. And don't hesitate to read [the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClass).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not the *nicest* syntax, but you could use:

```
data-ng-class="[button.isDisabled ? 'btn-disabled' : '', button.glyphicon]"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a function to `ng-class`.

```
<button type="button" ng-class="getClass()">...
```

and on the controller

```
 $scope.getClass = function(){
       return ($scope.button.isDisabled ? "btn-disabled " : " ") + ($scope.button.glyphicon || "");
   }
```

By adding this as a function you could reduce one extra watch that will be created while doing it inline in the template and abstract the logic out of html.