# AngularJS - Using Multiple Coniditons on ng-class

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-class, ng-show, angular-ng-if

I have a  using an ng-repeat. The  also has a ng-class true/false condition which is working. Am i able to add another condition to my true/false statement?

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in myData" ng-class="{true: 'green', false: 'red'}[data.IsPositive]">
    <td>
        {{data.Name}}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{data.CompanyName}}
    </td>
    <td>
        <span ng-show="data.Date | lessThanOneYear">Less than one year</span>
        <span ng-show="data.Date | lessThanOneYear">Greater than one year</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Essentially, i want to perform a check on if:

```
ng-class="[data.IsPositive] and [data.Date | lessThanOneYear]
```

So, if both of the above are true, then apply CSS class green... If false, apply red.

---

**Solution:**

I've had to use a mixture of the 2 suggestions provided. Essentially the condition with the filter needs to be wrapped in (), so:

```
ng-class="[data.IsPositive && (data.Date | lessThanOneYear)]
```

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871277/adding-multiple-class-using-ng-class

Comment: @MarioLevrero I don't think so. He asks about a more complex boolean expression. He's not asking about using more classes in a ng-class expression.

Comment: @BiAiB, Absolutely true. My fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing this, you need to understand that the expression between `[]` must evaluate to one of the indexes you specified in the associative array `{true: 'green', false: 'red'}`.

Then any expression that evaluate to true or false can be used, any boolean expression in this case.

```
[data.IsPositive and data.Date | lessThanOneYear]
```

Comment: added solution above.

Comment: It should be : `{true: 'green', false: 'red'}[data.IsPositive and data.Date | lessThanOneYear]`

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can:

```
{true: 'green', false: 'red'}[data.IsPositive && secondCondition && x>3 && whatever]
```

Comment: added solution above.