# ng-class same class multiple conditions

Tags: angularjs

Hi I'm using Angular with Twitter Bootstrap. I want to trigger the has-error class with one of the two errors. But neither:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : errorTime, 'has-error' : errorDate}">
```

nor:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : errorTime, errorDate}">
```

does work.

I thought it would work like this
[Adding multiple class using ng-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871277/adding-multiple-class-using-ng-class)

On the first solution it ignores the second parameter. So if the first is true it triggers has-error no matter what the second parameter is. (I switched them in the code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ng-class's value is supposed to be an object literal, whose attribute values are boolean. An object may not have the same attribute multiple times. And `errorTime, errorDate`is not a boolean expression. What you want is simply

```
{'has-error' : errorTime || errorDate}
```

Comment: So close I tried first: {'has-error' : errorTime || 'has-error' : errorDate} which didn't work. Thanks