# how to combine conditional class and data bound class in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, styles, ng-class

To apply different classes when different expressions evaluate to true:

```
<div ng-class="{'class1' : expression1, 'class2' : expression2}">
    Hello World!
</div>
```

To apply different classes a data-bound class using []

```
 <div ng-class="[class3, class4]">
        Hello World!
    </div>
```

I want to know if it is possible to combine the two types of template, i.e; have a conditional class using {} and a data-bound class using []?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to add multiple classes when expression gets to `true` ?

Comment: yes and also I want to add data bounded classes.

Comment: didnt clear to me. :( can you give a example ?

Comment: class3 and class4 are scope variables and I want to apply class1 and class2 based on expression1 and expression2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use following syntax

```
<div ng-class="[condition1 && 'class1', condition2 && 'class2', className]">
    Hello World!
</div>
```

className is a variable in scope. It's value gets applied to div.

Here is a example fiddle
[Conditionally apply class in angularjs](http://jsfiddle.net/codingsolver/s24vqw5e/1/)

Comment: This was very helpful, enjoy the bounty.

Answer (score 2):

Please see demo below

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {


  $scope.redClass = 'red';
  $scope.boldClass = 'bold';

});
```

```css
.border {
  border: 1px solid red
}
.red {
  color: red
}
.bold {
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">

    <p ng-class="[boldClass ,redClass,  1==1 ? 'border':'' ]">Hello Word</p>

  </div>
</div>
```