# how to add multiple class names with different conditions using ng class in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to add 2 class names in specific conditions to an element:

```
ng-class="(commentItem.comment | escapeHtml | direction)"
```

works for the first, getting text content of given html string using the "escapeHtml" filter and then getting direction of the text using the "direction" filter.
now I need to add another class to the same element this way:

```
ng-class="{'hidden': commentItem.isEditing}"
```

how to mix them both in a single ngClass directive?

**Note**
I think it's not possible to use the

```
{"exp1": condition1, "exp2": condition2}
```

because in the first condition, the filter returns the class name for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding multiple class using ng-class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871277/adding-multiple-class-using-ng-class)

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871277/adding-multiple-class-using-ng-class

Comment: @tpie this is not duplicated because of the difference between conditions

Comment: make a plunker please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NH2bzWdfE52U8lkLjlgq?p=preview).

The documentation for [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) regarding the argument states:

> Expression to eval. The **result of the evaluation** can be a string
>   representing space delimited class names, an array, or a map of class
>   names to boolean values.

It does not have to be a literal string or map or array. You can have a function return an array of classes like this:

```
ng-class="getClasses()"
```

And use whatever you like to construct the array in your controller. If you need filters use the `$filter` service.

If you don't want to use a controller function to handle view details you can pass an array to `ng-class` and for each element write na expression that returns a class name or an empty string:

```
ng-class="[!!redbg ? 'redbg' : '', 'gr' + 'een']"
```

Comment: I think creating a function which is not a controller nor a directive is an anti pattern approach. I used to resolve view-related issues inside view. cause if I didn't, I would've had a long list of utility functions by now. If you're sure there is no way to mix such different conditions, then I prefer to step back and prevent such a situation to happen. Thank you

Comment: How about: `<h1 ng-class="[!!redbg ? 'redbg' : '', 'gr' + 'een']">Hello Plunker!</h1>`. So use one expression for each element of an array and return a string with class name or empty. I don't think you will be able to use filters that way though.

Comment: One last option you have is to use both `ng-class` and `class` on a single element: `ng-class="{xxx: yyy}" class="{{expression returning class string}}"`

Comment: This is a better option. I used it. Thank you. Please add it in your answer