# Angular NgClass with multiple expressions

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I want to evaluate multiple expressions, but the class applied will be the same.  Here's an example...

```
<tr ng-class="{'highlight' : Expression1 || Expression2 || Expression3}">
```

If any of the expressions are true, it will apply the `highlight` class.  I have tried a few versions, but I'm not sure if this is the correct approach.

```
<tr ng-class="{'highlight' : Expression1, 'highlight' : Expression2 }">
<tr ng-class="[{'highlight' : Expression1, 'highlight' : Expression2 }]">
```

None of these seem to work, and all the example I have seen apply a different class to each evaluation.

Comment: what is the value of expression here../

Comment: Isn't http://stackoverflow.com/a/18871805/5259611 what you are looking for?

Comment: Have you tried if each expression works independently? ie <tr ng-class="{'highlight' : Expression1}"> <tr ng-class="{'highlight' : Expression2}"

Comment: In this fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/Farving/mj17u96t/) it seems like it is not possible to use appropriately on <tr>

Comment: @CarstenFarving, this used different classes per expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just fine and I believe the correct way to do it.

```
<tr ng-class="{'highlight' : Expression1 || Expression2 || Expression3}">
```

Comment: I have no idea why it didn't work previously, but this is now working - I can only assume the css or javascript file was cached! Thanks anyway.

Comment: Potentially :) if you're using chrome, open up the dev tools (f12) click on the cog, and then select disable cache (Should be in the top left). Also... spare an upvote?

Answer (score 0):

Would this be of use?

```
<!-- example with string syntax -->
<!-- use the type variable as a class -->
<div class="item ng-class:type;">Stuff Goes Here</div>

<!-- example with string syntax -->
<!-- use the styleOne and styleTwo variables as classes -->
<div class="item ng-class:[styleOne, styleTwo];">Stuff Goes Here</div>

<!-- example with evaluated data -->
<!-- add the text-error class if wrong is true -->
<div class="item ng-class:{ 'text-error': wrong };">Stuff Goes Here</div>
```

Taken from: [The many ways to use ng-class](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass)

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of angular library you are using.