# How to mix two ng-class expressions?

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

- I have two ng-class expression.
- ng-class="{true: 'none-block', false:
  'block'}[x.done&x.hide]"
- ng-class="{true: 'strike', false:
  'default'}[x.done]"
- How to mix them into one?

**the real question:**

```
<div ng-repeat="x in shoppingList |orderBy:'+done'|filter:search track by $index"  class="list-item" ng-class="{true: 'none-block', false: 'block'}[x.done&&hideMark]" style="padding-bottom:22px" >
    <a href="#" ng-click="done(x)" ng-class="{true: 'strike', false: 'default'}[x.done]" style="display:block">
          {{shoppingList.indexOf(x)}}. 
    <span class="thing" ng-bind="x.itemText"></span>
    </a></div>
```

Comment: Sorry got confused with your question. There's already a valid answer tho :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871277/adding-multiple-class-using-ng-class

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry my question is two different condition.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
ng-class="{true: 'none-block strike', false: 'block default'}[x.done]"
```

Comment: Thank you for your information. Sorry my question is two different condition.

Comment: post your real question. then we may can help. Otherwise its hard to predict the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
ng-class="{'block default': !x[done], 'none-block strike': x[done]}"
```