# ng-class with multiple options

Tags: angularjs

I'm fetching data using a REST API and one of the attributes returned can be any of 3 options;

The options are; Negative, Warning, Success.

I want to set a `class` using `ng-class` based on the value returned;

I'm able to do this but only for one;
Code below;

```
<div class="alert" ng-class="restaurantNotice(restaurant[0].notice)" ng-if="restaurant[0].notice.length">
    <div class="alert-inner inner-large" ng-bind="restaurant[0].notice"></div>
</div>

$scope.restaurantNotice = function(a) {
    return (a = Negative) ? 'negative' : '';
};
```

As you can see, if `a = Negative` then a `class negative` is applied else nothing is applied.

Now I want to check for all three options and apply 3 different classes respectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
<div class="alert" ng-class="{'negative' : restaurant[0].notice.length, 'warning' : restaurant[1].notice.length, 'success' : restaurant[2].notice.length}">
    <div class="alert-inner inner-large" ng-bind="restaurant[0].notice"></div>
</div>
```

duplicate of [Adding multiple class using ng-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871277/adding-multiple-class-using-ng-class)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of function in ng-class, use object

```
ng-class="{'negative' : restaurant[0].notice == 'Negative', 'warning' : restaurant[0].notice == 'Warning', 'success' : restaurant[0].notice == 'Success'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

In this way:

```
<p ng-class="{a: deleted, b: important, c: error}">Example</p>
```

if a is true, apply class deleted, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just going to set the same notice type (Negative, Warning, Success) as class then just convert to lower case and return from the function instead of putting conditions.

```
$scope.restaurantNotice = function(a) {
    return a.toLowerCase();
};
```

OR

```
<div class="alert" class="{{restaurant[0].notice | lowercase}}" ng-if="restaurant[0].notice.length">
```