# In Angular use ng-bind in class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-bind, class-attributes

In Angular I can write next :

```
class="{{ DayTypesClasses[request.typeId] }}"
```

which will set css-class according to expression value

But I've found that `ng-bind` can make the same but also save some time for this binding.

I've tried to use `ng-bind` in class, but it won't work.

```
class="ng-bind : 'DayTypesClasses[request.typeId]'"
class="ng-bind = 'DayTypesClasses[request.typeId]'"
class="ng-bind : DayTypesClasses[request.typeId]"
class="ng-bind:{{DayTypesClasses[request.typeId]}}"
```

How correctly should I use `ng-bind` in class-attribute?

[Link on documentation of `ng-bind`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) doesn't help me  :(

Comment: did you try `class="ng-bind : {{ DayTypesClasses[request.typeId] }}`"?

Comment: @sarvesh - it returns something like `class="ng-bind:dayoff"` but should be `class="dayoff"`

Comment: _"I've found that ng-bind can make the same"_ You only need to read the first sentence of the documentation to understand that this is not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass), either

```
<ANY ng-class="expression"> ... </ANY>
```

or

```
<ANY class="ng-class: expression;"> ... </ANY>
```

For example:

```
<p ng-class="{strike: deleted, bold: important, 'has-error': error}">Some example</p>
```

Comment: Hah, yes, this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

What you're expecting is to replace value of the `$scope` variable to class and for that you can use `ng-class`. You are just misunderstood the concept. `ng-bind` is a directive which you can use in different ways which add the content of your `$scope` varible to that tag insted of the attribute value.

You can see in below code, I've used `ng-class` in both ways. [More about ng-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871277/adding-multiple-class-using-ng-class)

```
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Todo</h2>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">

     <span class="ng-class:myClass">Demo text</span>
     <span ng-class="myClass">Demo text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/24111/)

Answer (score 0):

this is on the standard example and is working:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example61-production</title>


  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="bindExample">
  <script>
  angular.module('bindExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.name = 'Whirled';
    }]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <label>Enter name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></label><br>
  Hello <span class="ng-bind: name"></span>!
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/x1UQp5HGg8TBLUFtNacs?p=preview)

Comment: Emm, this example doen't bind something like css-class, instead it adds `Whirled` to `Hello`

Comment: then you should probably use the ng-class directive: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass