# How to change table row color based on 3 condition in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, html

I am created a AngularJs application.I need to change table row background color based on 3 condition.I know to change background color based on 2 condition using following way

```
<td ng-class="{'red': (variable == 1), 'blue': (variable ==2)}">{{data.material_or_service}</td>
```

I need to do above using three condition;that is **variable==3**.is any way to do it.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? I only see one condition on two separated properties in `ngClass`.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871277/adding-multiple-class-using-ng-class

Comment: Also, if you want another condition, just add another comma and an expression, eg: <div ng-class="{'class1': true, 'class2': true, 'class3': true}">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of ternary operators like this

```
<td ng-class="variable === 1 ? 'red' : variable === 2 ? 'blue' : 'green'">{{data.material_or_service}}</td>
```