# apply css dynamically in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ng-class

I have the following input.

HTML is as follows.

```
 <input type="number" ng-class="{negative: amount < 0}" ng-model="amount"/>
```

CSS is as follows

```
 .negative {
         color: red;
 }
```

If the amount is positive, it will display no css, if the amount is negative, it will use .negative as its css and display the font in red color.

However i want the positive class to show up when the amount is positive in number.

Can someone let me know how to satisfy both the positive and negative values.

Here is the css for positive.

```
.positive {
         color: blue;
}
```

Comment: For the future, try google first. "ng-class multiple" has a top result of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871277/adding-multiple-class-using-ng-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could have a complex ng-class.

`<input type="number" class="positive" ng-class="{'negative': amount < 0, 'positive': amount > 0, 'zero': amount == 0}" ng-model="amount"/>`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it without a function like so

```
<input type="number" ng-class="{positive: amount >= 0, negative: amount < 0}" ng-model="amount"/>
```

a [codepen](http://codepen.io/mkl/pen/YWVQzK) showing

Answer (score 1):

I believe you wanted to add class on field based on value entered, You could use `ng-class` with `function` which will decide which class will get applied.

```
<input type="number" ng-class="decideClass(amount)" ng-model="amount"/>

$scope.decideClass = function(value){
  return value => 0 ? 'positive': 'negative';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<input type="number" ng-class="{'positive': amount >= 0, 'negative': amount < 0}" ng-model="amount"/>
```