# Can't run ngAnimate animation

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

**UPD:** It's almost solved, problem was beacouse I've added second 'class' attribute in my div. Now it is works, but I still cant see animation of ng-repeat and now I have ***question N2*** :
**how to make collapsing and expending time different?** I want my divs collapsing three time faster then when they're expending. [Current Plank](https://plnkr.co/edit/4sH9ES?p=preview).

---

[Here is my example](https://plnkr.co/edit/DdjOZe?p=preview)

[And here is working example from the other SO question (I'm using absolutly the same method!)](http://plnkr.co/edit/V9w2EwUh0unszf62TZZB?p=preview)

I can't find out why animation not shown nither on ng-repeat, nor ng-show.
Html:

```
  <body ng-controller="mainCtrl as vm" class="container">
    <div ng-repeat="user in vm.users" class="repeat-item">
        <my-user-info user="user"></my-user-info>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Directive code:

```
angular.module('main').directive('myUserInfo', function(){
    var directive = {
        templateUrl: 'userInfoCard.directive.html',
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            user: '='
        },
        controller: ctrl
    }
    return directive;

    function ctrl($scope){
        console.log($scope)
        $scope.knightMe = function(user){
            //debugger;
            user.rank = 'knight';
        }
        $scope.collapse = function(){
            $scope.collapsed = !$scope.collapsed;
        }        
    }
```

Directive template:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading" ng-click="collapse()">
        <h4 class="no-margin"><b>Name:&nbsp;</b>{{user.name}}, <b>Age:&nbsp;</b>{{user.age}}</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" ng-show="!collapsed" class="fadein fadeout">
        <div ng-show="!!user.address">
            <h4>Address:</h4> {{user.address.street}}
            <br /> {{user.address.city}}
            <br /> {{user.address.country}}
            <br />
        </div>
        <div ng-show="!!user.friends && (user.friends.length > 0)">
            <h4>Friends:</h4>
            <ul class="friends">
                <li ng-repeat="friend in user.friends">{{friend}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="!!user.rank"><h4>Rank: {{user.rank}}</h4></div>
        <div ng-show="!user.rank">
            <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="knightMe(user)">Knight Me</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And css:

```
/* ====================== */

.fadein,
.fadeout {
  -webkit-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1.5s;
  -moz-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1.5s;
  -o-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1.5s;
  transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1.5s;
}

.fadein.ng-hide-remove,
.fadeout.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active {
  opacity: 0;
  display: block !important;
}

.fadeout.ng-hide-add,
.fadein.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block !important;
}

/* ====================== */

.repeat-item.ng-enter,
.repeat-item.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition:0.5s linear all;
  transition:0.5s linear all;
}

.repeat-item.ng-enter,
.repeat-item.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity:0;
}
.repeat-item.ng-leave,
.repeat-item.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity:1;
}
```

[image: Result]

The .ng-enter and .ng-enter-active CSS classes are generated and appended to the element by AngularJS when the ngIf tells it that it's adding a new item into the repeat list. Depending on the animation, other CSS classes are added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Change

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-show="!collapsed" class="fadein fadeout">
```

to

```
<div class="panel-body fadein fadeout" ng-show="!collapsed">
```

you have two class declaration on the div.  May be you wanted to do ng-class={'fadein fadeout' : !collapsed}.

> Working plunkr:  https://plnkr.co/edit/MsgJxp?p=preview
>
> Check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871277/adding-multiple-class-using-ng-class) for [Adding multiple class using ng-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871277/adding-multiple-class-using-ng-class)

Comment: BTW, now it is works, but I still cant see animation of ng-repeat and now I have ***question N2*** :
**how to make collapsing and expending time different?** I want my divs collapsing three time faster then when they're expending.