# How to set a right parsed if statement with class attribute and ng-class with Angularjs in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node-red

I have struggling with the syntax with angularjs (used in nodered). I want to set diffrent bootstrap classes on each row depending on the workorder.state in a list.
if the "if statement are true" it should use success class. But the if are never true it always use default "info". Even if the output of {{workorder.state}} are "Ready". Any suggestions?

```
<div class="list-group" ng-repeat="workorder in workorders">
    <button type="button" class="ng-class:{{workorder.state}} === 'Ready' ? list-group-item list-group-item-success responsive-width : list-group-item list-group-item-info responsive-width;">
          <span class="brnodisplay">{{workorder.state}}</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

I get below error in browser console.

> app.min.js:142 Error: [$parse:syntax] 
>      http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.10/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2…
>      ve-width%20%3A%20list-group-item%20list-group-item-info%20responsive-width
>       at http://127.0.0.1:1880/ui/js/app.min.js:29:426
>       at throwError (http://127.0.0.1:1880/ui/js/app.min.js:256:200)
>       at t.object (http://127.0.0.1:1880/ui/js/app.min.js:256:33)
>       at t.primary (http://127.0.0.1:1880/ui/js/app.min.js:252:151)
>       at t.unary (http://127.0.0.1:1880/ui/js/app.min.js:251:503)
>       at t.multiplicative (http://127.0.0.1:1880/ui/js/app.min.js:251:249)
>       at t.additive (http://127.0.0.1:1880/ui/js/app.min.js:251:76)
>       at t.relational (http://127.0.0.1:1880/ui/js/app.min.js:250:416)
>       at t.equality (http://127.0.0.1:1880/ui/js/app.min.js:250:241)
>       at t.logicalAND (http://127.0.0.1:1880/ui/js/app.min.js:250:94)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use interpolation `{{}}`  and filter common classes(which should be there irrespective of the check) to `class`.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="list-group" ng-repeat="workorder in workorders">
    <button type="button" class="list-group-item  responsive-width" ng-class="{'list-group-item-success': workorder.state === 'Ready' ,'list-group-item-info':'workorder.state !== 'Ready' }">
          <span class="brnodisplay">{{workorder.state}}</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

**For more reference**:

1. [Adding multiple class using ng-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871277/adding-multiple-class-using-ng-class)
2. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your ng-class to this (`ng-class` is used in lieu of `class`, not in addition to as you have used):

```
ng-class="workorder.state === 'Ready' ? 'list-group-item list-group-item-success responsive-width' : 'list-group-item list-group-item-info responsive-width'"
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="list-group" ng-repeat="workorder in workorders">
    <button type="button" class="list-group-item  responsive-width" ng-class="{'list-group-item-success': workorder.state === 'Ready' , 'list-group-item-info': workorder.state !== 'Ready' }">
        <span class="brnodisplay">{{workorder.state}}</span>
    </button>
</div>
```