# How to put multiple class values with multiple conditions in the ng-class of Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am very new to Angular.js. In my project, there are two classes named style1 and style2.

The requirement is applying two styles with `ng-class` attribute in the template itself. I am not using separate function for this, but a boolean value named 'bool' which is dynamic.

The following are conditions

> if (bool) then the style1 & style2 applies 
> else style1 is applies.

eg:

```
<input ng-class="something"/>
```

Each one class value is assigned my cases more than 1 class value is need assign.

How can I put this logic in the `ng-class`? I tried so many ways but no use.

Comment: is it angular js or angular ? you have tagged both

Comment: Please check my answer. It might help you out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding multiple class using ng-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871277/adding-multiple-class-using-ng-class)

Comment: Viz it is not duplicate in your link for each expression each one class value is assigned my cases more than 1  class value is need assign.Any way thanks for your help to edit my query.Thanks for your kind help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.bool = true;
}
```

```css
.style1 {
  color: #f31313;
}

.style2 {
  background-color: #baeae6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <div ng-class="{'style1 style2' : bool, style1 : !bool}">
      Hello World!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly

```
<div ng-if="thisistrue" ng-class="style1">
  blah
</div>
<div ng-if="otheristrue" ng-class="[style2,style3]">
  blah
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may proceed as follows :

Based on description you provided : `style1` is always applied irrespective of the value returned by `bool` variable(don't know why you named variable`bool` always use meaningful names like `Isstyle2Applied`  )

- Simply apply `style1` using class attribute.
- Use `ng-class` for `style2` based on your condition.
- When condition is `true` both classes will applied on desired `HTML
  element`

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.bool = true;
  $scope.bool2 = false;
}
```

```css
.style1 {
  color: #f31313;
}

.style2 {
  background-color: #baeae6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <div class='style1' ng-class="{'style2' : bool}">
      Hello World!
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class='style1' ng-class="{'style2' : bool2}">
      Hello World!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer by @anu is fine. But for your condition given;
"if(bool) then the style1 & sytle2 applied else style1 is applied."

style1 changes text color 
style2 changes background color

so, if boolean = true both text and background is applied,
if false only text color is applied.

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.bool = true;
}
```

```css
.style1 {
  color: #f31313;
}

.style2 {
  background-color: #baeae6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <div ng-class="{'style1 style2' : bool, style1 : !bool}">
      Hello World!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Enjoy learning 'Angular' :)