# Toggling the visibility of div class with Angular

Tags: css, angular

I am trying to change the visibility of a CSS class .handle to 'hidden' after a button has been clicked. I tried to just insert a modified class by doing [ngClass]="'handle.hidden'" after the button has been toggled but this didn't work.

HTML File

```
<div class="expand-collapse">
 <button class="button-text title-text" (click)="toggleButton()">
  <span class="minimize"></span>
---> <div [ngClass]="'handle.hidden'"></div>
 </button>
</div>
```

CSS File

```
.handle {
    height: 25px !important;
    position: relative;
}

.handle.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.handle.visible {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: [The documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#description) seems to imply that if you want to add multiple classes they should be space-separated.

Comment: Use https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf `*ngIf`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding multiple class using ng-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871277/adding-multiple-class-using-ng-class)

Answer (score 1):

The problems is with the class name used in your ngClass binding. It must be:

```
<div [ngClass]="'handle hidden'"></div>
```

Or:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'handle': true, 'hidden': true}"></div>
```

In html code attribute class with value `handle hidden` match in css file as rule `.handle.hidden`

Sorry my english

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.hidden = false;
}

toggleButton() {
   this.hidden = !this.hidden;
}
```

```
<div class="expand-collapse">
 <button class="button-text title-text" (click)="toggleButton()">
  <span class="minimize"></span>
   <div class="handle" [ngClass]="{'hidden': hidden}"></div>
 </button>
</div>
```

```
.handle {
    height: 25px !important;
    position: relative;
    &.hidden {
       visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

No need to add class visible, as it's visible by default.

Answer (score 1):

I would say there are two approaches. First is the conditional [ngClass] which means, in your toggleClass() function you are toggling the value of a `boolean`, like `this.divIsVisible = !this.divIsVisible`, then

```
<div class="handle" [ngClass]="divIsVisible ? 'visible' : 'hidden'"></div>
```

The second one is applying the *ngIf ***structural directory*** on the `div`, then

```
<div class="handle" *ngIf="divIsVisible"></div>
```

Also note that, ***ngIf** entirely removes the `div` from the DOM, while the visibility only hides it, but it's still on the page.

Answer (score 0):

this is easier using class directives, just add the handle class normally if it's supposed to always be there and then:

```
<div class="handle" [class.hidden]="isHidden"></div>
```

where isHidden is your component variable that gets toggled.  A "visible" class is redundant as it will become invisible / visible just by adding and removing the hidden class

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to add the `hidden` class conditionally while keeping track of the display status.

```
<button (click)="isHidden = !isHidden">
<div [class.hidden]="isHidden"></div>
```

In your `.ts` file, add and initialize `isHidden:boolean`.