# Apply css based on condition

Tags: css, angular

I am trying to apply a css class based on a condition. This is my code but it does not seem to apply the class correctly.

Basically if `selectedEmployee.isHrEmailAddress` is true then I want to override `section` with `.section-postal`

***HTML***

```
<section [ngClass]="{'.section-postal': selectedEmployee.isHrEmailAddress}">
    <div class="page-container">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <form *ngIf="contactDetailsForm" [formGroup]="contactDetailsForm">
                <div class="text-left">
                    <div class="flex flex-row sm:flex-col md:flex-row-reverse lg:flex-col-reverse xl:flex-row">
                        <div class="check-container text-left" style="width: 450px;">
                            <div class="flex flex-row sm:flex-col md:flex-row-reverse lg:flex-col-reverse xl:flex-row">
                                <div class="line">
                                    <p-checkbox name="isHrEmailAddress" formControlName="isHrEmailAddress"
                                        [(ngModel)]="selectedEmployee.isHrEmailAddress" binary="true"
                                        (onChange)="toggle('emailCheckId')">
                                    </p-checkbox>
                                    <span class="ml-2 pt-4" style="font-size: 15px;">I am using my email address on the
                                        member's behalf</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="note" *ngIf="selectedEmployee.isHrEmailAddress">
                        <span>Please note: You will need to confirm the employee's postal address, so that they can be
                            contacted in future.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

***css***

```
  section {
    height: 500px;
  }

 .section-postal {
    height: 650px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ternary operator in ngClass to select the class based on condition

```
[ngClass]="selectedEmployee.isHrEmailAddress ? 'section-postal' : 'section'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the dot from the class name in the `[ngClass]` value.

```html
<section [ngClass]="{'section-postal': selectedEmployee.isHrEmailAddress}">
```

The dot is used in the [CSS selector syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) to denote a class. The class in the HTML should be without the dot.

```css
section {          /* denotes the `<section>` tag: type selector syntax */
  height: 500px;
}

.section-postal {   /* denotes the `section-postal` class: class selector syntax */
  height: 650px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In html you must use the class name without the dot.

```
[ngClass]="{'section-postal': selectedEmployee.isHrEmailAddress}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use binding, if you just want to override a single class. Here is the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-types-and-targets), check out the section `class property`

```
<section [class.section-postal]="selectedEmployee.isHrEmailAddress"></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here We Go ,

```
   .section-postal { // css file
        color:red;
    }

    i = true; // in ts file

     <section [ngClass]="{'section' : i, 'section-postal' : !i }"> //html file
```

With reference Adding Multiple Class using `ngClass` :
[Adding multiple class using ng-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871277/adding-multiple-class-using-ng-class)