# Angular ngClass with two dynamic property binding classes?

Tags: css, angular

I want to make buttons whose color and border color are set as independent variables in the component controller. The [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) and [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871277/adding-multiple-class-using-ng-class) show how to do multiple static classes but not multiple dynamic classes. I tried a few ways but these didn't work:

```html
[ngClass]="[color] [border]" // doesn't work

[ngClass]="[color], [border]" // doesn't work

[ngClass]="[color, border]" // not dynamic binding

[ngClass]="{[iClass]: true, [iBorder]: true,}" // doesn't work
```

Maybe I should use one dynamic class with in the view and spin up the CSS properties into a class on the fly in the component controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'class1': expression1, 'class2': expression2}"></div>
```

Comment: I hope this is the answer You are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I put the logic in the controller but with `ngClass` the logic should be in the view. This eliminates the need for dynamic classes.

```html
[ngClass]="{ 
   green: l2Language === 'English', 
   gray: l2Language === 'Spanish',
   red: l2Language === 'Chinese',
   finnishBlue: l2Language === 'Finnish',
   blackBorder: l1Language === 'English' || 'Spanish',
   width180: l1Language === 'English' || 'Spanish'
}"
```

This puts multiple classes (color, border, width) on a single button, controlled by multiple variables (languages). When the language is `English` the button is green with a black border and a width of 180 pixels. When the language is `Chinese` the button is red with no border and no set width.