# angular ngclass how to use multiple classes and conditions

Tags: angular

Hi I have a component wrapped in a div that I want to change the class name of based on something like a button click. I have about 5 CSS classes that I want to be able to toggle the div class between using ng class. My questions how can I write ng class to use multiple Booleans for each class name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding multiple class using ng-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871277/adding-multiple-class-using-ng-class)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML CODE**

```
<div
  class="normal"
  [ngClass]="{
    green: selection.nature,
    blue: selection.sky,
    red: selection.love,
    yellow: selection.friendship
  }"
>
  <button (click)="select('nature')">NATURE</button>
  <button (click)="select('sky')">SKY</button>
  <button (click)="select('love')">LOVE</button>
  <button (click)="select('friendship')">FRIENDSHIP</button>
</div>
```

**TS CODE**

```
selection = {
    nature: false,
    sky: false,
    love: false,
    friendship: false,
  };
  select(value: string) {
    Object.keys(this.selection).forEach((k) => (this.selection[k] = false));
    this.selection[value] = true;
  }
```

I have created a stackblitz for the same if you want to check it in action. Please find it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k5wpfx)

Please mark it as answer if it resolved your query. Happy Coding :)